webscraping data doesn't work - selenium and python
I try to scrape games and odds from this url Merkurbets with selenium and python.
The element for "team-name" looks like. Is _ngcontent-ng-c1043474636 in div-tag a problem for selenium to find the text() of div-tag?
<div _ngcontent-ng-c1043474636="" class="team-name">FAC Wien</div>

I've tried a lot of combination to get data out of this url, here are just one example:
# games_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cdk-accordion-child-3"]/div/div/games-list-partial/div')
games_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cdk-accordion-child-3"]/div/div/games-list-partial/div/games-list-game[1]')
print('games_elements: ', games_elements)
for game in games_elements:

    try:
        # Mannschaftsnamen extrahieren
        teams = game.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="cdk-accordion-child-3"]/div/div/games-list-partial/div/games-list-game[1]/div/div[1]/div/game-details-summary/div/div/div/div[1]')
        # Quoten extrahieren
        odds = game.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="cdk-accordion-child-3"]/div/div/games-list-partial/div/games-list-game[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/market/div/div[2]/div/tip[1]/div/button/span[2]/div/tip-odds/div/div')

        if len(teams) == 2 and len(odds) >= 3:
            home_team = teams[0].text
            away_team = teams[1].text
            home_odds = odds[0].text
            draw_odds = odds[1].text
            away_odds = odds[2].text

            games_data.append({
                "Home Team": home_team,
                "Away Team": away_team,
                "Home Odds": home_odds,
                "Draw Odds": draw_odds,
                "Away Odds": away_odds,
                "Zeitstempel": timestamp  # Zeitstempel
            })
        else:
            logging.warning("Unerwartete Anzahl von Teams oder Quoten für ein Spiel gefunden.")
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        logging.error(f"Fehler beim Extrahieren der Daten für ein Spiel: {e}")

or here
# Alternativ: Versuche eine längere Wartezeit mit Sichtbarkeitsprüfung
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    # Greife auf ein sichtbares 'team-name'-Element zu
    team_name_element = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "team-name"))
    )
    print(team_name_element.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Fehler: {e}")
finally:
    # Speichere die Seite, um den Inhalt zu überprüfen
    page_source = driver.page_source
    with open('page_source.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(page_source)
    print("HTML-Inhalt gespeichert.")

and always chromedrive accept cookies and scroll down
def scroll(driver):
    height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print('height: ', height)
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        time.sleep(1) # <- traditional hack
        hnow = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        print('hnow: ', hnow)
        if hnow == height:
            break
        height = hnow

# Starte den Webdriver
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Optional: Ohne Fenster anzeigen
service = Service(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")  # Pfad zu chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Öffne die Webseite
driver.get("https://www.merkurbets.de/de/sports/0/s1/1")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
# Cookies akzeptieren
accept_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cookiescript_accept"]')
accept_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
scroll(driver)
# Warte 10 Sekunden (probiere dies nur zu Debugging-Zwecken)
time.sleep(2)
team = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,  './/div[contains(@class,"team-name")]')

I've try a lot of variation with XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, CLASS_NAME etc.
but everytime I get empty list, no elements.
Please help.

This question is similar to: How to use Selenium with Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

thank you for answer. But this question doesn't help by this problem. It's not about  input fields. Here we don't get any data. I've tried "all" kind of variation with driver.find_elements(By.XPATH...)
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME...)
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR...)
and so on.

You want to "scrape", not "scrap" the site. You'll probably find better search results if you don't misspell crucial keywords.

Thank you for correction hint. I' ve search a lot with different key words.

you probably need to wait for all elements to have loaded properly.


You could intercept the response of request(https://oddsservice.msw-mb-de.cashpoint.solutions/odds/getGames/10):


Or you could send the api request directly.

If you want to extract data by XPath or CSS selector from HTML, you should locate the iframe first:

Or you can open the page directly: https://v3.msw-mb-de.cashpoint.solutions/de/sports/0/s1/1

